# Problem with align getting an error for an extra &

Tags: align

[image]i have a small problem. As you can see in the two pictures i am trying to write an equation and i am using the align fuction, the thing is that in my previous template it was working but in my new one it doesn't work and i cannot find what is different from the previous one that's why i need your knowledge to help me with that.

[image]

```
\begin{align}
    u_\textrm{d} + ju_\textrm{q} &= |\boldsymbol{\textit{u}}_\textrm{s}|e^{j(\theta_\textrm{o} - \theta)} &= \\ &=|\boldsymbol{\textit{u}}_\textrm{s}|\cos{(\theta_\textrm{o} - \theta)} + j|\boldsymbol{\textit{u}}_\textrm{s}|\sin{(\theta_\textrm{o} - \theta)}\\
    \Rightarrow u_\textrm{q} &= |\boldsymbol{\textit{u}}_\textrm{s}|\sin{(\theta_\textrm{o}-\theta)}
\end{align}
```

Comment: This fragment has no problem (except a weird second column). PLease post a small, but complete code, reproducing the error

Comment: Also, the error message doesn't mention `&`, but `$`.  Those are quite different.

Comment: please post a small complete document that gives the error. The fragment you posted is not complete but if I add `\documentclass` and `\usepackage{amsmath}` then it runs without error. Note however `u_\textrm{q}` should be `u_{\textrm{q}}` or better `u_{\mathrm{q}}`

Comment: The error you show in the screenshot  is about a missing `}` in a `\textrm`  that is in an `align*` environment (note the `*`) the code you show is an `align` environment and has no such error.

Comment: Oh you are using breqn!!! in that case the bad markup `u_\textrm{.}` does not work at all, with `breqn` you have to properly brace the arguments. but are you sure you want to load breqn? (you don't seem to be using it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not supply a complete example but a similar error can be obtained with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    u_\textrm{d} + ju_\textrm{q} &= |\boldsymbol{\textit{u}}_\textrm{s}|e^{j(\theta_\textrm{o} - \theta)} &= \\ &=|\boldsymbol{\textit{u}}_\textrm{s}|\cos{(\theta_\textrm{o} - \theta)} + j|\boldsymbol{\textit{u}}_\textrm{s}|\sin{(\theta_\textrm{o} - \theta)}\\
    \Rightarrow u_\textrm{q} &= |\boldsymbol{\textit{u}}_\textrm{s}|\sin{(\theta_\textrm{o}-\theta)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

which produces

```
! Argument of \textrm  has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11 \end{align}

?
```

The superscript should always be braced `u_{\textrm{q}}` in some cases the standard definition allows the braces to be dropped but it is not good practice and with `breqn` it doesn't work at all.

You don't seem to be using `breqn` here just standard `amsmath` enviornments so not loading the package is one option, or add the missing braces. `\mathrm` is more suitable than `\textrm` here so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    u_{\mathrm{d}} + ju_{\mathrm{q}} &= |\boldsymbol{\mathit{u}}_{\mathrm{s}}|e^{j(\theta_{\mathrm{o}} - \theta)} &= \\
 &=|\boldsymbol{\mathit{u}}_{\mathrm{s}}|\cos (\theta_{\mathrm{o}} - \theta) + j|\boldsymbol{\mathit{u}}_{\mathrm{s}}|\sin (\theta_{\mathrm{o}} - \theta)\\
    \Rightarrow u_{\mathrm{q}} &= |\boldsymbol{\mathit{u}}_{\mathrm{s}}|\sin (\theta_{\mathrm{o}}-\theta)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ohhh i just copied for another project, when i removed the breqn it worked completely. Thank you very much for your help i was so frustrated yesterday couldn't find what was wrong

Comment: @ΓιωργοςΤσιάκας removing breqn makes the error go, but you should still add the braces. The fact that `x_\textrm{o}` works without braces is just weird and doesn't apply to similar commands like `x_\mbox{o}`